# Printing to two Printers at the same time

Tags: windows, printer, print-spooler

I have two thermal receipt printers installed on a PC.

Is there a way to print to two printers at the same time?

Using Windows XP.

It will be printed via browser.

Comment: Are these printers both the same make and model? How are they connected (USB, LPT, COM)?

Comment: Yes both are same make and model.. Both connected to Serial Ports (COM).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked into this for archiving purposes not too long ago. Although my needs were a little different, I needed to print to a physical printer and a PDF printer for archiving, I figured it is worth sharing my findings.

The two solutions I found to be the best were: [Print distributor](http://www.frogmorecs.com/printdistributor) and [Multi print](http://www.edocfile.com/MultiPrint.htm). Both cost money but I assume this is for a business so stability is important (I assume you have zebras which are already unreliable). I also managed to get it working with [ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) but it was very flaky and would sometimes stop working altogether (would require spooler restart). Overall print distributor was by far the easiest to setup and get going.

Answer (score 0):

What about printer pooling, and setting it to print two copies? In the Printer Properties, go to the Ports tab, and choose printer pooling, and choose the additional port